# Is boost reliable when it gives such an error?

Tags: c++, boost

Here is the kind of errors I get, that is definitely not related to my code

```
/usr/bin/c++  -D_TIMER -g -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include -I/Users/issam/include   -o output.o -c project.cpp
In file included from project.cpp:756:
In file included from /Users/issam/include/project.hpp:123:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include/boost/regex.hpp:31:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include/boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp:39:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include/boost/regex/regex_traits.hpp:27:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_traits.hpp:39:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:40:
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include/boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp:39:17: error: no type named 'list' in namespace 'std'
   typedef std::list<value_type> list_type;
           ~~~~~^
```

if I compile a file that only includes:

```
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
```

It compiles without any problem and creates the .o file. Here is the verbose output of the compilation

```
/usr/bin/c++  -D_TIMER -g -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include -o output.o -c newFile.cpp -v
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.8.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name newFile.cpp -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 136 -v -g -coverage-file /Users/issam/folder/output.o -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.2 -D _TIMER -I /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/pd/kcfk19hd5mv9vjwsvpqtk_tc0000gq/T/clang-module-cache -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/issam/folder -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 168 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.8.0 -fobjc-dispatch-method=mixed -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o output.o -x c++ newFile.cpp
clang -cc1 version 4.2 based upon LLVM 3.2svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10/x86_64"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.0.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/i686-apple-darwin8/"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/backward"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.2/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

Comment: Add an `#include <list>` on your `project.hpp`

Comment: It's *definitely* related to your code, because I see your `project.cpp` and `project.hpp` mentioned in the include trace. Don't make such claims unless you prove them by [*showing* your code (a short as possible version of it)](http://sscce.org).

Comment: You might want to try to create the smallest C++ source that reproduces the problem.  Other possible troubleshooting tools: use the `-M` option to see if incorrect or suspicious headers are being included,  and/or `-E` to see the preprocessor output in case a macro is screwing things up (doesn't seem likely to me given the error message, but macros can do very strange things).

Comment: @ Arne Mertz Ok I take that remark. The error is maybe in my code. But there is something wrong with the error that is declared by the compiler. Maybe the compiler is failing to point the right error which would not surprise me from a c++ compiler. Thus how can I show you the part of my code that is not working if the compiler is failing to point it out?

Comment: @Arne Mertz I copied my code on another machine with the same version of boost installed. The code compiles correctly. There is maybe something wrong with my installation or from the fact that there is another version of of boost installed on /user/local.

Comment: Do you define any macros in your code? Can you show them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp` has the following on line 23:

```
#include <list>
```

so for an error such as `"error: no type named 'list' in namespace 'std'"`, it seems likely that your installation of Boost or your compiler toolchain has a problem.

What happens if you try to compile a C++ source file that contains only:

```
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited my post to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

I looked it up - the [mentioned header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp) file includes `<list>`, so everything is ok there.

Chances are that you messed up the namespaces by including either `boost/regex.hpp` or your own `project.hpp` inside a namespace or by using directives before the `#include` of either header.

The compiler tells you about an error at the location where it actually sees there was an error, in this case somewhere deep in the guts of the boost headers. Often, when an error is made, you don't notice it immediately, but much later when things look screwed up. It's the same for the compiler this time. It can't say exactly *where* you messed up, but only *how it knows* something is wrong.